# How to take mysql dump of the mysql db every hour

Tags: mysql, linux, cron

hey I am newbie to scripting in linux.I want to take a sqldump of my database every hour, I have gone thorough couple of blogs i was able to write a script which will take the dump of my database but I do I make it run every hour in the crontab.

Kindly help me out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set up a crontab entry like this:

```
0 * * * * /usr/bin/mysqldump --user=sqluser --password=sqlpass -A > /tmp/database.sql
```

This will run the command `/usr/bin/mysqldump --user=sqluser --password=sqlpass -A > /tmp/database.sql` on the hour, every hour. This will dump all database schemas into the file /tmp/database.sql (adjust as required for your setup) using the username sqluser and the password sqlpass (again, adjust for your setup)

For more information about crontab syntax, you can refer to [this page](http://content.hccfl.edu/pollock/unix/crontab.htm)